# ActiveJDBC + Backbone.js Generated attribute name not usable

Tags: java, html, backbone.js, activejdbc

I am using ActiveJDBC to access a third-party db. There is a column named "users/year". I am not happy with that but cannot change it.
This results is an attribute "users/year" in the json thats the basis for my backbone.js model. Now if I want to access that attribute in the following template:

```
<li><%= name+ ' ' + users/year %></li>
```

Of course it doesn't work. I tried escaping but that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Since I am new to activeJDBC and backbone.js is there a way off mapping the attribute to a acceptable variable name? Or other possible solutions for that? Should I switch from activeJDBC to something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a parse method to your collection or model to remap your attribute to a usable name:

```js
var  M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function(resp) {
        if (resp['users/year']) {
            resp['users_year'] = resp['users/year'];
            delete resp['users/year'];
        }

        return resp;
    }
});
```

and change your template accordingly

```html
<li><%= name+ ' ' + users_year %></li>
```

A Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/rnKSD/

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can wrap the dynamic getter of your model with a getter wrapper:
http://code.google.com/p/activejdbc/wiki/SettersAndGetters#No_%22standard%22_setters/getters???

Comment: Can you provide an example? I looked at that page before, didn't help me, sry. As far as I understand it the problem is the attribute name not the getter.

Comment: instead of doing this: 
user.get("address");
you add a getter:
class User{
  public String getAddress(){ return getString("address"); }
}